# How to Insert Image into Jtable(Customize code)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I got many difficulties when I tried to insert in JTable which netbeans generated. 
this capture of the customize code of my JTable. 
[image]

so how I set Image into jtable in my class code accurately.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `getColumnClass()` method so the table can choose an appropriate renderer. Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableIcon extends JFrame
{
    public TableIcon()
    {
        ImageIcon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("about16.gif");
        ImageIcon addIcon = new ImageIcon("add16.gif");
        ImageIcon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

        String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {aboutIcon, "About"},
            {addIcon, "Add"},
            {copyIcon, "Copy"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable( model )
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return (column == 0) ? Icon.class : Object.class;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableIcon frame = new TableIcon();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Mr.camickr look to my page above , the array column and row does not have name so what the parameter of the DefaultTableModel??

Comment: Customize my example to meet your requirements. Only you know the exact requirements.