# Adding image to JTable

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I am trying to display an image inside a JTable but I am encountering a problem. All that is inside of my JTable cell is this: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4ec6ca37. I have read on here about how to do and people said it would work just fine with ImageIcon. This is pretty much how I am doing it:

```
ImageIcon icon = null;
...
icon = new ImageIcon('gets the image and convert it to a Strings');
tableModel.setValueAt(icon, i, 4);
```

Relevant facts(?): My tableModel is an AbstractTableModel, I am iterating through my JTable (that's why it says ..(icon, **i**, 4);) to set in different pictures which I take from a list.

Is there anything I have missed? Feels like there's an easy mistake here, I hope I gave enough information for you guys to understand, thnaks in advance!

Comment: `My tableModel is an AbstractTableModel` - your TableModel extends AbstractTableModel and implements the methods of the TableModel interface. Why are you extending AbstractTableModel and implementing all the basic code when you can just use a DefaultTableModel and override the `getColumnCloass(...)` method as suggested below?

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `getColumnClass()` method in your table model implementation and return `Icon.class` for the appropriate column index in order to allow the table to apply the right [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html). For example:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final int ICONS_COLUMN = 0;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == ICONS_COLUMN ? Icon.class 
                                           : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

    ...
}
```

See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for further details.

Comment: Ah, okay. I am overriding my getColumnClass at the moment and it looks like this: public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        } I guess this's wrong then

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that. Since you know your model (you are modeling it) you can perfectly retrieve the appropriate class for each column. @Fjondor

Comment: @Fjondor, that code should work, assuming the data in the first row is not null. The code suggested here will work in all situations and is therefore better.

Comment: It works, but i have several columns. One of them should contain an image. Every column works except for the image one. When I try the code above the first column is just blank. Image column still just giving me nonsense

Comment: *"When I try the code above the first column is just blank. Image column still just giving me nonsense"* As I've said you have to retrieve `Icon.class` for the ***appropriate*** column index. In the example `0` is the first column, just replace that with the right index. If the column with images is the 1st one then `0`, if the 2nd one then `1` and so on. @Fjondor

Comment: @dic19 Okay, now I see. I chose the right column now but image isn't showing. Might it be because of the cell being so small? I thought the cell would expand to the size of the image as I insert it.

Comment: `I thought the cell would expand to the size of the image as I insert it.`. The cell does not automatically resize. If you don't see the Icon, then you probably didn't read the image correctly. Here is a complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638474/how-to-insert-image-into-jtablecustomize-code/20639809#20639809